# how to use compound pattern with dynamic imports nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

so i was trying to use dynamic imports in nextjs to import a component that uses [compound pattern design](https://www.patterns.dev/posts/compound-pattern/)(Dialog); but i get the following error while trying to use properties of Dialog:

> TS2339: Property 'Title' does not exist on type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
>   Property 'Title' does not exist on type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>'.

following is the Dialog component implementation that uses compound pattern:

```
const Dialog = ({children}) => (
    <>
        <NativeDialog
            open={true}
            PaperProps={{
                sx: {
                    width: "700px",
                    borderRadius: "15px",
                    "@media only screen and (max-width: 720px)": {
                        width: "100vw",
                        height: "100vh",
                    },
                },
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </NativeDialog>
    </>
);

const DialogHeader = () => (
    <div className={styles.headerContainer}>
        <div style={{marginRight: "37%"}}>
            <IconButton>
                <Link href="/" passHref>
                    <CloseIcon/>
                </Link>
            </IconButton>
        </div>
        <div>
            <TwitterLogo size="S"/>
        </div>
    </div>
);

const DialogTitle = ({children}) => (
    <NativeDialogTitle>
        <div className={styles.titleContainer}>{children}</div>
    </NativeDialogTitle>
);

const DialogContent = ({children}) => (
    <NativeDialogContent>
        <div className={styles.formContainer}>{children}</div>
    </NativeDialogContent>
);

const DialogActions = ({children}) => (
    <NativeDialogActions>
        <div className={styles.actionContainer}>{children}</div>
    </NativeDialogActions>
);

Dialog.Header = DialogHeader;
Dialog.Title = DialogTitle;
Dialog.Content = DialogContent;
Dialog.Actions = DialogActions;

export default Dialog;
```

and here is the component that dynamically imports Dialog:

```
const Dialog = dynamic(
    () => import('../../Dialog'),
    {loading: () => <Spinner/>}
)

const Signin = ({signinState, setSigninState, handleSignin, setAuth}) =>
    (
        <>
            <Dialog>
                <Dialog.Title>
                    <Dialog.Header/>
                    <div className={`font font-eb ${styles.header}`}>
                        Sign in to Twitter
                    </div>
                </Dialog.Title>
                <Dialog.Content>
                    <div className={styles.contentContainer}>
                        <div className={styles.contentItem}>
                            <Button className={buttonStyles.whiteButton}>
                                <ThirdPartyAuth state="in" company="Google"/>
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.contentItem}>
                            <Button className={buttonStyles.whiteButton}>
                                <ThirdPartyAuth state="in" company="Apple"/>
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.contentItem}>
                            <Divider orientation="horizontal" text="or" width={300}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.contentItem}>
                            <TextField
                                sx={{width: 300}}
                                label={<div className="font">email</div>}
                                value={signinState.email}
                                onChange={e => setSigninState(prevState => {
                                    return {...prevState, email: e.target.value}
                                })}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.contentItem}>
                            <TextField
                                sx={{width: 300}}
                                label={<div className="font">password</div>}
                                value={signinState.password}
                                onChange={e => setSigninState(prevState => {
                                    return {...prevState, password: e.target.value}
                                })}
                            />
                        </div>
                        {(signinState.clientError || signinState.serverError) && <div className={styles.contentItem}>
                            <div className={styles.error + " font font-m"}>
                                {signinState.clientError ? signinState.clientError : signinState.serverError ? signinState.serverError : ""}
                            </div>
                        </div>}
                        <div className={styles.contentItem}
                             onClick={() => handleSignin(signinState, setSigninState, setAuth)}>
                            <Button
                                className={`
              ${buttonStyles.blackButton} font font-eb`}
                            >
                                Signin
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.contentItem}>
                            <Button
                                className={`
              ${buttonStyles.whiteButton} font font-b`}
                            >
                                Forgot password?
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                        <div
                            className={`${
                                styles.contentItem + " " + styles.help
                            } font font-m`}
                        >
                            Don&apos;t have an account?
                            <div style={{display: "inline-block"}}>
                                <Link href="/signup" passHref>
                                    <div className={styles.signup}>Sign up</div>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Dialog.Content>
            </Dialog>
        </>
    );


export default Signin;
```

using Dialog with regular import expression doesnt create this problem but dynamically importing it does. any thoughts is appreciated.